# how do you find all the nodes that are reachable in a graph

Tags: c, graph, tree, breadth-first-search

Given a node in a graph that is reachable, how do you find all the nodes that are reachable ? How would you enable parallel computation of this information ? Given a number of cores, how many threads would you choose ?

For the first part, i would go with the Breadth first Search and second part, i think somehow i should use the strnegth of Map-reduce but not able to understand how? 
Could you please help. Appreciate your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a worked out example in the article: [breadth-first graph search using an iterative map-reduce algorithm](http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/breadth-first-graph-search-using-iterative-map-reduce-algorithm)

Comment: Thank you Raymond. I am sorry, i should have googled it more before asking here.